# php date and mysql timestamp comparison

Tags: php, mysql

How can I do a select from a db field that uses a timestamp when all I have from php is a date?

```
$date = 2012-10-03;
```

something like:

```
"select value from table where completed_date = $date"
```

only the value for completed_date is really something like "2012-10-03 02:16:10" what I really would like is all values that are the same day as $date and for the query to almost disregard the time aspect of the timestamp for this query. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Please note you also need to specify your `$date` variable like `$date = '2012-10-03';` (note the sinlge quotes around data value.

Comment: @NullUserException pls make your answer an answer so i can mark it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your provided date is already a valid mysql datestamp, it can be as simple as:

```
SELECT ... WHERE DATE(completed_date)='2012-10-03'
```

Comment: This will work, but would not enable you to use any index on the field.

Comment: yes, but since the date isn't stored in a native format, you'd HAVE to do something like, or use string operations, for anything involving partial date matches anyways.

Answer (score 1):

you need to try something like this,

```
"select value from table where completed_date like '$date%'"
```

Comment: This is index friendly answer if you are looking for all entries on same date as your timestamp (not timestamp + 24 hours or whatever).

Comment: ya, I guessed the OP was just searching for the date part of the field, as he/she wants to `disregard the time aspect`.

Answer (score 0):

use DATE_FORMAT to format mysql date:

```
"select value from table where DATE_FORMAT(completed_date,'%Y-%m-%d') = $date"
```

Comment: I won't down vote, but you should not be using functions in this manner.

Comment: You would not be able to take advantage of the any index on completed_date field.

Comment: @NullUserException Using functions in the `WHERE` clause may render any possible indexes unused.

Answer (score 0):

If your database field is a Unix timestamp, you would use `FROM_UNIXTIME` detailed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

If your databse field (`col`) is of `datetime` type, you would `SELECT ... WHERE col LIKE '2012-10-03%'`.

If your database field (`col`) is of `date` type, you would `SELECT ... WHERE col = '2012-10-03'`.

Answer (score 0):

If `completed_date` is a timestamp field, not varchar, then you could do something like this:

```
"SELECT value FROM table WHERE completed_date>=? AND completed_date<?"
```

And bind in the parameters:

```
$date="2012-10-03";
$start=date("Y-m-d G:i:s",strtotime($date));
$end =date("Y-m-d G:i:s",strtotime($date.' +1day'));
```

Comment: I prefer using a `BETWEEN` clause instead of `x >= y AND x <= z`. Arrows always confuse me.

Comment: @NullUserException However, `BETWEEN` is not inclusive. Passing `2012-10-03` would search `2012-10-03 00:00:00`.

Comment: @njk man says it is [inclusive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Comment: @NullUserException Not when passing just the date. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/631f6/1).

Comment: @NullUserException If you request records between two dates, the result does include the second date.

Comment: @njk That means it *is* inclusive; you'd have to use `BETWEEN YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00 AND YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59` to get all dates that are `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: @NullUserException That's not correct. The manual states that the `BETWEEN` operator is equivalent to `min <= expr AND expr <= max`, which is not the case with `datetime`. Requesting `BETWEEN ... AND '2012-10-04'` would fetch records only UP TO `2012-10-04 00:00:00`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17572/discussion-between-nulluserexception-and-njk)

Answer (score 0):

I like coder1984's answer as one that doesn't require a schema change.  I would however suggest just adding a field in your database that is a date field if this is how you are typically going to query the data.

Comment: @njk No, more meant as alternate answer if OP wants to consider making a DB schema change.  If not, I think coder1984 has the best solution.

Comment: Considering I answered before him, I'm giving myself credit =p

Comment: @njk, just fyi, the answers are ordered time-wise from bottom to top. just saw this misinterpretation a lot lately, so had to clarify :)